# Cannot convert type 'bool' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<My.Models.MyDataList>'

Tags: linq-to-sql, linq-to-objects

```
public IQueryable<MyDataList> GetMyDataList(int id)
{
    var result = db.MyDataLists.All(b => b.MyDataListID== id);
    return (IQueryable<MyDataList>)result ;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `All` method returns a boolean indicating whether *all* of the items match a condition.

You're trying to call `Where`, not `All`.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is `Where()` not `All()`. `All()` is like "Do all items in the list satisfy this condition or not?" not "get all items that satisfy condition".

Answer (score 0):

All returns a bool indicating if all items in the list match the predicate.  You're then trying to cast bool to `IQueryable<MyDataList>`

Answer (score 0):

```
public IQueryable<MyDataList> GetMyDataList(int id)  
{      
     return db.MyDataLists.Where(b => b.MyDataListID== id);
}
```

Thats probably what you wanna do.